# How to clean up tools::R_user_dir()

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

The [CRAN policy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html) states:

> For R version 4.0 or later (hence a version dependency is required or only conditional use is possible), packages may store user-specific data, configuration and cache files in their respective user directories obtained from tools::R_user_dir(), provided that by default sizes are kept as small as possible and the contents are actively managed (including removing outdated material).

I want to store a small RSQLite database in a location given by `tools::R_user_dir()`. While this is easy enough, I have no idea how I could actively managae this location, b/c if I understand the policy correctly I am responsible for deleting this file if it is not needed anymore.

Thus, I am wondering whether there is a package specific deinstallation hook which I could use to clean up the file in case my package gets deinstalled?

Comment: You could use the fact that all of CRAN (plus by now removed packages) are mirrored at github.com/cran/ and search with for use of `(tools;:)R_user_dir`.  You may find a pattern you like and understand and can adapt.  I generally make use of the directory _optional_ so that my tests do not write so that I do not have clean up under the watchful eyes of you-know-who.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel The search `(tools;:)R_user_dir` at github.com/cran/ did not work for me. Is it the bottom search bar you're referring to? Is there something more I need to place there than `(tools;:)R_user_dir`?

Comment: I apologize for the typo: I meanr `(tools::)R_user_dir` but mistyped. The parens are shorthand for optionality, so please try search for either one or both of [`tools::R_user_dir`](https://github.com/search?q=org%3Acran%20tools%3A%3AR_user_dir&type=code) and [`R_user_dir`](https://github.com/search?q=org%3Acran+R_user_dir&type=code).  I just got 238 and 378 hits, respectively. And I made those two links so you can just click on them.

Comment: D'oh. The bottom bar at [github.com/cran/](https://github.com/cran/) is for "Find repository" so not even `R_user_dir` was working. Thank you for correcting the optionality.